# Using grequests to send a pool of requests, how can I get the response time of each individual request?

Tags: python-requests, grequests

I am using the grequests python library to send GET requests asynchronously to our server.

I cant figure out how to get the server response time for each individual request within the pool of requests being sent out?

```
unsentrequests=(grequests.get(u) for u in self.urls) # make a pool of requests
responses=grequests.map(unsentrequests) # send the requests asynchronously
```

To get the start time of a request-response pair I could do the following:

```
grequests.get(u,headers={'start':time.time())
print responses[0].request.headers['start_time']
```

But how can I grap the time that the response was received at?

Comment: You have three questions [webapps.se] that have some good answers. Perhaps you can take some time and evaluate them, as you do on [so].

Comment: done. apologies . thanks.

Comment: Try this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656037/python-grequets-to-get-time-for-each-http-response-individually

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`grequests`, like `requests`, support an `hook` keyword argument where you can assign a function that does something with the response object:

```
def do_something(response):
    print response.status_code

unsentrequests=(grequests.get(u, hooks = {'response' : do_something}) for u in self.urls) 
responses=grequests.map(unsentrequests)
```

I prefer to use `requests` directly in a loop using `gevent` to have a more explicit code:

```
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_socket()
from gevent.pool import Pool
import requests

def check_urls(urls):

    def fetch(url):
        response = requests.request('GET', url, timeout=5.0)
        print "Status: [%s] URL: %s" % (response.status_code, url)

    pool = Pool(20)
    for url in urls:
        pool.spawn(fetch, url)
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Why do you put the fetch() function as a sub-function to check_urls()?  (I'm just learning python, so I'm trying to figure out what the adv would be, versus just putting it in the more general scope)

Comment: There is no reason, it is just that I'm a bad programmer ;-) Jokes aside you could rewrite my code defining `fetch` outside the main function.

Comment: Doesn't this print the status only after each 20th request? Is there a way to print the status after each request with a pool size > 1?