# python grequets to get time for each http response individually

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a python script using grequests to send http requests to server. The problem is that I need to get response time of each request. I have used hooks but still i can't find a single method to display exact response time. I used time.time() but I cant keep track of each request.
Below is the code.

```
def do_something(response, *args, **kwargs):
    print('Response: ', response.text)
    roundtrip = time.time() - start
    print (roundtrip)

urls = ["http://192.168.40.122:35357/v2.0/tokens"]*100
while True:
    payload = {some_payload}

    start = time.time()
    unsent_request = (grequests.post(u, hooks={'response': do_something}, json=payload) for u in urls)
    print(unsent_request)
    print(grequests.map(unsent_request, size=100))
```

Answer (score 1):

grequests is just a wrapper around requests library. Just use the [.elapsed attribute](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.elapsed) from the latest library, this way:

```
response_list = grequests.map(unsent_request, size=100)
for response in response_list:
    print(response.elapsed and response.elapsed.total_seconds() or "failed")
```

Comment: Just for the confirmation, is it showing time in seconds?

Comment: `.elapsed.total_seconds()` will give you the number of seconds, yes. Notice that `.elapsed` is a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects): you can get seconds, microseconds, ...

Comment: @QuratulAinShafiq could you please accept the answer? This worked for me seamlessly.